# Prevent JavaScript Injection on Timer

Tags: javascript, setinterval, xss, firebase

I am making a browser game where every 10 seconds, `i` is incremented, and the points algorithm uses `i` to determine the number of points awarded. The obvious way (to me) to do this is to use `setInterval(10000)` for the timer, and run the points calculation inside of the function.

**How do I prevent a JavaScript injection that increases** `i`**, making the app think that the user has actually been playing for longer than he really has?**

I am using Firebase as the back-end. As a PHP programmer, I would normally just do server-side validation of the player's points when he submits them by checking start & end times. I suppose I can do this in Firebase as well, so I probably just answered my own question...

Still, is there a way to just prevent a JavaScript injection? (**Prevention**, not server-side **Detection**).

Comment: You should be trying to limit the scope of the variable instead of preventing code injections.

Comment: Chances are your javascript already makes it impossible to inject a new value for i into a function since it won't be available outside of that function, but we'll never know since you didn't include any code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make variables essentially private, which means that it will be impossible for the user to change them through plain JS injection.  But that won't stop someone from intercepting your Javascript with a debugger, from intercepting your communication between client and server, or from doing all sorts of other fiddling.

To make a variable private, just include it inside a function, execute that function, and return something that includes a function referencing that variable.  This is called a `closure`.  It's quite easy to do.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/WynX5/1/) there is a `counter` variable that is updated every second (not every ten seconds -- I'm in a hurry!  :-) ) and another variable, `basePoints`  that together add to the current score.

Publicly exposed is a function that allows you to add to the basePoints value, but nothing allows you to add to the counter.  I don't think you can do that without getting inside the JS engine (as a debugger does.)  The main point is that there is no way within Javascript to update the `counter` variable.

```
var app = this.app = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var basePoints = 0;
    var div = document.getElementById("score");
    var addPoints = function(nbr) {
        basePoints += nbr;
        display();            
    };

    document.getElementById("add20").onclick = function() {
        addPoints(20);            
    };

    var display = function() {
        var points = counter + basePoints;
        div.innerHTML = points + " points";
    };

    setInterval(function() {
        counter += 1; 
        display();
    }, 1000);

    return {
        addPoints: addPoints
    };
}());​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent simple manipulation of the variable via things like bookmarklets by just making sure that the variable is internal to a function context and is NOT a global variable and not accessible from the global scope.  That can be as simple as putting it into a self executing function context like this:

```
(function() {
    var i;

    // code that uses i

    setTimeout(function() {
        more code that uses i
    }, 1000);
})();
```

In this case, only code inside that first function block can get to the variable `i`.

Note, as others have said, this doesn't prevent more complicated manipulations that actually change the source javascript before the page executes it or break in the debugger and manipulate things there as there is no way to prevent those, but it does prevent the simplest ways of reaching into a page and changing the variable (like from a bookmarklet).

Answer (score 1):

There is virtually no way to prevent any sort of highscores hacking by calculating the value on the client side and subsequent push to the server side. Only obfuscation and different tricks can make the hacking more or less complicated, but they cannot prevent it at all. That is why server side validation or event better server side calculation is preferred.